# How can I obtain a solution for the equation $a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + 1$?

Tags: diophantine-equations

For the equation $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$, the solution is:

- $a = m^2 - n^2, b= 2mn, c = m^2 + n^2$
- $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $m > n$, free to choose

How is a similar solution obtained for the equation $a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + 1$?

I'm familiar with it, but don't know how to obtain it.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351491/integral-solutions-of-hyperboloid-x2y2-z2-1/709219#709219

Comment: @individ: Why didn't you give a link directly to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/74931/131263?

Comment: @barakmanos Because the formula itself just drawn there.