# Number of integer points on a rotational hyperboloid of two sheets.

Tags: number-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

There are many integer points on the hyperboloid of two sheets
$x^2+y^2-z^2=-1$.

(0,0,1), (2,2,3), (4,8,9),...

Let us denote such set as H.

I will consider only the upper sheet $z>0$, but sign variations in x and y are in it. The number of such points with z coordinate below or at a certain value n will be denoted by P(n)

$P(n) = |(x,y,z) \in H, 0<z\leq n|$

as an example

P(1)=1 ... because only (0,0,1) fits the description
P(2)=1 ... we don't get anything else
P(3)=5 ... we pick up 4 sign variations of (2,2,3)
...

I was wondering how quickly this sequence grows and it seems that P(n) is very close to n, asymptotically speaking. Is there a reason for it? What are good bounds for $|P(n)-n|$?

For the first half milion values I calculated it below.

[image: empirical data]

Comment: Even for $x=y$ we have infinitely many integer solutions.

Comment: I know, I am more interested why is P(n)~n or in any explicit asymptotics for P(n)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351491/integral-solutions-of-hyperboloid-x2y2-z2-1/709384#709384

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74931/integral-solutions-of-x2y21-z2/789929#789929

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I am more interested in asymptotics.

Comment: edited the last paragraph, to stress that I am interested in the asymptotics of the blue curve rather than finding particular solutions