# Enumerating a subset of rationals: a variation on the Calkin–Wilf tree

Tags: elementary-number-theory, rational-numbers, trees, pythagorean-triples

I've been doing some recreational maths on the [Calkin–Wilf tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calkin%E2%80%93Wilf_tree), which enumerates all positive irreducible fractions in the form of a binary tree, similar to the [Stern–Brocot tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Brocot_tree). Instead of enumerating all positive rational numbers, I became interested in finding a tree that generates only a particular subset of rationals, namely those of the form $m/n$ with the properties:

1. $m/n$ is positive and irreducible,
2. $m > n$,
3. $m$ and $n$ have opposite parity.

You may already know where I'm going with this. After some trial-and-error, I indeed managed to find a set of transformations that accomplish this; in fact, I found *two* sets of transformations. The first set looks like this:

$$
    f_A\left(\frac{m}{n}\right) = \frac{m+n}{2n},\qquad
    f_B\left(\frac{m}{n}\right) = \frac{2m}{m+n},\qquad
    f_C\left(\frac{m}{n}\right) = \frac{2m}{m-n},
$$

or in matrix form:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
        m_A\\
        n_A
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1\\
        0 & 2
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        m\\
        n
    \end{pmatrix},\quad
    %
    \begin{pmatrix}
        m_B\\
        n_B
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 0\\
        1 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        m\\
        n
    \end{pmatrix},\quad
    %
    \begin{pmatrix}
        m_C\\
        n_C
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 0\\
        1 & -1
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        m\\
        n
    \end{pmatrix}.
$$

The second set of transformations is
$$
f_{A'}\left(\frac{m}{n}\right) = \frac{2m-n}{m},\qquad
f_{B'}\left(\frac{m}{n}\right) = \frac{2m+n}{m},\qquad
f_{C'}\left(\frac{m}{n}\right) = \frac{m+2n}{n},
$$
or
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
        m_{A'}\\
        n_{A'}
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & -1\\
        1 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        m\\
        n
    \end{pmatrix},\quad
    %
    \begin{pmatrix}
        m_{B'}\\
        n_{B'}
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 1\\
        1 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        m\\
        n
    \end{pmatrix},\quad
    %
    \begin{pmatrix}
        m_{C'}\\
        n_{C'}
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2\\
        0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        m\\
        n
    \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Starting with $2/1$, we obtain the two trees

[image: rational trees]

It is straightforward to prove that each tree indeed enumerates all rationals with the properties 1-3, without duplicates (I'll leave that as an exercise).

Unlike the binary Calkin–Wilf and Stern–Brocot trees, these trees are *ternary*. My question is: is there a deeper reason for this? **Why do these transformations come in sets of three? Can it be proven that these two are the only possible sets of transformations?**

---

If you are wondering why I'm interested in these fractions, there is a fascinating link between the trees I found and the two known [trees of Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples). Indeed, the tuples $(m,n)$ with the properties 1-3 generate all primitive Pythagorean triples as $(m^2-n^2, 2mn, m^2+n^2)$. You can check that

$$
\begin{align}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 1 & -1\\
        -2 & 2 & 2\\
        -2 & 1 & 3
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        m^2 - n^2\\
        2mn\\
        m^2 + n^2
    \end{pmatrix}
    &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        m_A^2 - n_A^2\\
        2m_A\,n_A\\
        m_A^2 + n_A^2
    \end{pmatrix},\\[1em]
    %
    \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & -1 & 1\\
        2 & 2 & 2\\
        2 & 1 & 3
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        m^2 - n^2\\
        2mn\\
        m^2 + n^2
    \end{pmatrix}
    &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        m_B^2 - n_B^2\\
        2m_B\,n_B\\
        m_B^2 + n_B^2
    \end{pmatrix},\\[1em]
    %
    \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 1 & 1\\
        2 & -2 & 2\\
        2 & -1 & 3
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        m^2 - n^2\\
        2mn\\
        m^2 + n^2
    \end{pmatrix}
    &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        m_C^2 - n_C^2\\
        2m_C\,n_C\\
        m_C^2 + n_C^2
    \end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & -2 & 2\\
        2 & -1 & 2\\
        2 & -2 & 3
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        m^2 - n^2\\
        2mn\\
        m^2 + n^2
    \end{pmatrix}
    &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        m_{A'}^2 - n_{A'}^2\\
        2m_{A'}\,n_{A'}\\
        m_{A'}^2 + n_{A'}^2
    \end{pmatrix},\\[1em]
    %
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 2\\
        2 & 1 & 2\\
        2 & 2 & 3
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        m^2 - n^2\\
        2mn\\
        m^2 + n^2
    \end{pmatrix}
    &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        m_{B'}^2 - n_{B'}^2\\
        2m_{B'}\,n_{B'}\\
        m_{B'}^2 + n_{B'}^2
    \end{pmatrix},\\[1em]
    %
    \begin{pmatrix}
        -1 & 2 & 2\\
        -2 & 1 & 2\\
        -2 & 2 & 3
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        m^2 - n^2\\
        2mn\\
        m^2 + n^2
    \end{pmatrix}
    &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        m_{C'}^2 - n_{C'}^2\\
        2m_{C'}\,n_{C'}\\
        m_{C'}^2 + n_{C'}^2
    \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
$$
The first set of 3x3 matrices was discovered by Price (2008), the second by Berggren (1934) and Barning (1963) (see the wiki article). At the time I was unaware of these matrices, so I was surprised to find out that I re-discovered something that wasn't known until fairly recently, with just a few days of mathematical doodling...

I've done some reading on these trees, including [this top answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4222298/76680) on 'near-Pythagorean' triplets, but I'm wondering if my own questions can be answered without any reference to Pythagorean triplets.