# Are there any parametric solution for this Pythagoras type quadratic Diophantine equation?

Tags: diophantine-equations

I wont to find a parametric solution for the Diophantine equations
$x^2+y^2=m(m+1)$ and
$x^2-y^2=m(m+1).$
I can simplify them up to
$(2x)^2±(2y)^2+1=(2m+1)^2,$ but after that I'm stuck. How can I obtain a parametric solution for this type of equations?

Comment: Are you considering these two equations as a system, or separately? As a system, there are definitely no integer solutions.

Comment: Look there is a solution.   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74931/integral-solutions-of-x2y21-z2/789929#789929

Comment: Of course separately.

Comment: Simple ones are, $$(2n)^2 + (2n^2)^2 + 1 = (2n^2+1)^2$$ $$ (p^2q+p+q)^2-(2pq+1)^2 + 1 = (p^2q+p-q)^2$$ What you are looking for are (separate) solutions to $x^2+y^2 = z^2\pm 1$. See http://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/003 for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should write a more General solution of the equation.

$$x^2+y^2=z(z+a)$$

If you ask any integers: $k,s$ - and use the solutions of the equation Pell.

$$p^2-2k(k-s)t^2=a$$

The solution, you can write:

$$x=p^2-(3k-2s)pt+(k-s)(2k-s)t^2$$

$$y=p^2-(3k-s)pt+k(2k-s)t^2$$

$$z=(p-(2k-s)t)^2$$

$$.......$$

$$x=(kp+s(s-k)t)t$$

$$y=((k-s)p+kst)t$$

$$z=(2k^2-2ks+s^2)t^2$$

You can write a simple solution without the Pell equation.

If: $a=2t+1$

$$x=b$$

$$y=b^2+t(t+1)$$

$$z=b^2+t^2$$

If: $a=2t$

$$x=b$$

$$y=\frac{b^2+t^2-1}{2}$$

$$z=\frac{b^2+t^2+1}{2}-t$$