# Representation of integers by ternary quadratic form $x^2+y^2-z^2$

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms

Let $Q$ be the ternary quadratic form $Q(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z^2$. Since $Q(0,p+1,p)=2p+1$ and
$Q(1,p+1,p)=2p+3$, we see that for every integer $k$, the equation $E_k:Q(x,y,z)=k$ always
has a solution. Is it known for which integers $k$ there are infinitely many solutions to $E_k$ ?

Comment: Solution there.    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74931/integral-solutions-of-x2y21-z2/789929#789929

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $$x^2-k=z^2-y^2$$ A number can be represented as a difference of two squares, so long as it is not twice an odd number. For any $k$, you can find infinitely many $x$ such that $x^2-k$ is not twice an odd number, hence, infinitely many solutions.