# Ternary Quadratic Forms

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms

Let $Q(x,y,z) = ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}_{\neq 0}$. Suppose that the Diophantine equation $Q(x,y.z) = 0$ has a non-trivial integral solution. Show that for any rational number $g$, there exist $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $Q(x,y,z) = g$

I have trouble starting, any help will be appreciated! I know Legendre's theorem for the necessary and sufficient condition of $Q(x,y,z) = ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2$ having non-trivial integral solutions, but I am not sure how to apply that.

Comment: What book are you using? An isotropic ternary does represent all integers and rational numbers over $\mathbb  Q.$  This follows from material in Cassels (1978) or Dickson (1939), but is probably not stated explicitly in either.

Comment: I am using An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers 5th Edition
by Ivan Niven (Author), Herbert S. Zuckerman  (Author), Hugh L. Montgomery (Author).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is about ternary quadratic forms with integer coefficients. We use the ordering in
[Lehman 1992](http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/%7Ekap/Lehman_1992.pdf) and [Watson 1954](http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/%7Ekap/Watson_Representation_1954.pdf).
I like how Watson writes it, writing $zx$ instead of $xz.$ The ordered sextuple
$$ \langle a,b,c, r,s,t \rangle $$ refers to the form
$$ f(x,y,z) = a x^2 + b y^2 + c y^2 + r y z + s z x + t x y  $$
The Hessian matrix, of second partial derivatives, is

$$
H = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
2 a & t & s \\
t & 2b & r \\
s & r & 2c
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The discriminant is half the determinant of $H$ and therefore an integer,
$$  \Delta = 4abc + rst - a r^2 - b s^2 - c t^2. $$

Oh, right. Given a column vector
$$
U = 
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{array}
\right),
$$
we have
$$  f(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{2} \; \;  U^T H U. $$

We will say that $f$ represents another form $g,$ with Hessian $G,$ if there is an integer matrix $P$ with $\det P \neq 0,$ such that
$$  P^T H P = G. $$ Note that $ \det G = \det H \left( \det P \right)^2$  is still nonzero.

Suppose that $f$ is isotropic over the integers. This means that there is some $(u_1, u_2, u_3),$ not all zero, with  $f(u_1, u_2, u_3)= 0.$

**Theorem:** if $f$ is isotropic with nonzero discriminant, then there is a nonzero integer $n$ such that $f$ represents $n (y^2 - zx).$

For an appropriate nonzero integer $k,$  we will arrange  $  P^T H P = G $  with

$$ G= k \; \; 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

It took me three steps to prove this, so I will present it that way. The first statement of this that I know is pages 507-508 of [Fricke Klein 1897](https://books.google.com/books?id=H5kLAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Vorlesungen%20%C3%BCber%20die%20Theorie%20der%20automorphen%20%20Functionen&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMIscb4rNvYxgIVSCiICh3qMwQX#v=onepage&q=muesli&f=false)

This is also on page 303 of [Cassels](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486466701.html)
but is not part of the online preview. ADDED it is also the intent of Example 1 on page 28, which refers to Lemma 2.1 and Corollary 1 on page 15 (by way of a hint for the exercise).

[image]

Here is page 301 from Cassels, you can see the relevant themes

[image]

First, we have
$$
U = 
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
u_1 \\
u_2 \\
u_3
\end{array}
\right).
$$
The hypothesis is that
$$  U^T H U = 0. $$
On the other hand, we are told that the determinant of $H$ is nonzero, which tells us that $HU \neq \vec{0}.$ It follow that there is a nonzero integer vector
$$
V = 
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
v_1 \\
v_2 \\
v_3
\end{array}
\right)
$$
such that
$$ V^T H U = 0. $$
For example, using the ordinary cross product, we could simply use $V = (HU) \times U.$ Such a $V$ is nonzero because $U$ and $HU$ are nonzero, but are not parallel; indeed, the ordinary dot product $(HU) \cdot U = 0.$

We may take any third vector as the final column of a matrix

$$
P = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
u_1 & v_1 & w_1 \\
u_2 & v_2 & w_2 \\
u_3 & v_3 & w_3
\end{array}
\right)
$$
as long as the determinant is nonzero.  The outcome is that, with some integers $i,j,k,l,$
$$
P^T H P = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & l \\
0 & 2i & j \\
l & j & 2k
\end{array}
\right).
$$
That is, $f$ represents
$$ \langle 0,i,k,j,l,0 \rangle $$

Next, we take a new matrix
$$
Q = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & j^2 - 4ik \\
0 & 1 & -2jl \\
0 & 0 & 4il
\end{array}
\right).
$$
It took me a long time to find $Q.$ We now have, with some nonzero integers $m,n,$
$$
Q^T P^T H P Q = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & n \\
0 & 2m & 0 \\
n & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right).
$$
Finally, we take a diagonal matrix $R,$
$$
R = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
m & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -n & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -n
\end{array}
\right).
$$
We reach
$$
R^T Q^T P^T H P Q R = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & -m n^2 \\
0 & 2mn^2 & 0 \\
-m n^2 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right) \; \; = \; \;  m n^2 \; \; 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

That is, $f$ represents an integer multiple of $y^2 - zx.$ Let us call that $N(y^2 - z x).$ Again, $f$ represents a nonzero multiple of
$$ \langle 0,1,0, 0,-1,0 \rangle $$

If we want to represent some integer $e,$ we may simply take $y = 0, x = -1, z = Ne.$ Then $y^2 - zx = Ne$ and $y^2 - zx = N^2 e.$ finally,
$$ \left( \frac{y}{N} \right)^2 - \frac{z}{N} \frac{x}{N} = e.  $$

I see that the question asks to represent a rational number $T.$ Well, there is some square number $S^2$ multiplied by the rational gives an integer. Represent $S^2 T,$ then divide $x,y,z$ by $S.$

Thursday, 20 October: the matrix entries I came up with for the general case may be much, much larger than required. On page 28, Cassels asks about $3 x^2 - 2 y^2 - z^2.$ I have a computer program to find these expressions with small numbers. I will not bother doubling the diagonal entries,

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & 2 & -2 \\
0 & 2 & 4 \\
1 & -1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & 0 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & -1 \\
-2 & 4 & 1
\end{array}
\right) = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & 12 \\
0 & -24 & 0 \\
12 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
That is,
$$ \langle 3,-2,-1,0,0,0 \rangle $$ represents
$$ \langle 0, -24,0,0,24,0 \rangle $$ or
$$ -24 \cdot \langle 0, 1,0,0,-1,0 \rangle. $$

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./homothety_indef 3 -2 -1 0 0 0    0 -24 0 0 24 0    4
         24 :     3    -2         -1      0    0    0
      13824 :     0   -24          0      0   24    0
--------------------------
      2      0      1 
      2      2     -1 
     -2      4      1 
--------------------------
```