# Symmetry Groups of Quadratic Forms and Lattices

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, representation-theory, integer-lattices

In this question I want to consider a quadratic form $\mathcal{Q}$ on an even integral finite rank lattice (not necessarily self-dual, unimodular, or positive definite).

*Given an explicit such quadratic form, are there elementary methods to write down exactly what the full symmetry group is?  If so, say one has found a subgroup of the full symmetry group, is there a way to be sure that in fact the complete symmetry group has been found?*

One example of interest to me is the following.  Consider the lattice $\Gamma =\mathbb{Z}^{3}$ endowed with quadratic form,

$$\mathcal{Q}(a,b,c) = 2(ab + ac + bc)$$

I found a group representation of $\text{PGL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ on the lattice automorphisms of $\Gamma$ defined by the following three automorphisms:

$$\sigma_{A}(a,b,c) = (b,a,c), \,\,\,$$ 
$$\sigma_{B}(a,b,c) = (a+2c, b+2c, -c), \,\,\,$$ 
$$\sigma_{C}(a,b,c) = (a+2b, 2b+c, -b).$$

(The above are the images of the three usual generators of $\text{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$.)  One can show easily that the three automorphisms above *preserve the quadratic form $\mathcal{Q}$.*  Therefore, whatever the full symmetry group of $\mathcal{Q}$ is, I believe it at least contains $\text{PGL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ as a subgroup.  Now in this case I'm nearly certain the full symmetry group is much larger, so as indicated in my question above, how can I determine what the rest of it is, if indeed this is possible for this form?

Comment: alright, mailed you a modest output file, about 1080 lines. At your department address

Comment: Thanks so much!  I appreciate it.  So it is indeed true that any of my integral triples taking the same value on the quadratic form are related by some element of the symmetry group you propose?  I will try to convince myself of this both experimentally and analytically.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: perhaps. The fundamental result of Siegel for indefinite forms is that we can count the genus average representation count. For an indefinite form, the average as such is infinite , so we switch to counting the finite number of orbits. That is, for any represented number, there is a finite set of orbits under the automorphism group for representations of that number. Now, for this particular form, I suspect this is always just one orbit, but that is not the general case; automorphisms and representations of target numbers need not be the same thing.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  So it isn't by definition true that there is only one orbit under the automorphism group for each quadratic form value?  I thought that was a defining characterization of the symmetry group and if you had more than one orbit, it meant you had not found the full group!

Comment: no, you might want to look at some of my answers for indefinite binary forms; let me find one with several orbits... here is a good one, four orbits under the oriented group http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739752/how-to-solve-binary-form-ax2bxycy2-m-for-integer-and-rational-x-y/739765#739765

Comment: Okay great, I had a big gap in what I thought these automorphism groups were!  Do you happen to know if there's a notion of some enhanced symmetry group which identifies all elements within each orbit?  Something containing the automorphism group.

Comment: Found it: the AMS is indeed coming out with an English translation, next week,  of Fricke-Klein (1897) with modern commentary as appendicies. Main : http://bookstore.ams.org/ctm-3/  Table of Contents:  http://bookstore.ams.org/ctm-3/~~FreeAttachments/ctm-3-toc.pdf

Comment: This book: , in particular Erster Band: Die Gruppentheoretischen Grundlagen  https://books.google.com/books?id=H5kLAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Vorlesungen+%C3%BCber+die+Theorie+der+automorphen++Functionen&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMIscb4rNvYxgIVSCiICh3qMwQX#v=onepage&q=muesli&f=false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form $yz + zx + xy$ is $SL_3 \mathbb Z$ equivalent to $y^2 - zx.$ (Actually its negative, doesn't matter). Therefore the entire automorphism group is the image of $PSL_2 \mathbb Z.$

See, for example, page 23 in Magnus, *Noneuclidean Tessellations and Their Groups.*

Given  $\alpha \delta - \beta \gamma = 1,$  this gives all elements in the oriented automorphism group of the ternary quadratic form $g(x,y,x) = y^2 - zx.$  That is

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha^2 &  \alpha \gamma &  \gamma^2\\
2 \alpha \beta & \alpha \delta + \beta \gamma & 2 \gamma \delta\\
\beta^2    &  \beta \delta  & \delta^2
\end{array}
\right) 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 &  -1\\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
-1    & 0  & 0
\end{array}
\right) 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha^2 & 2 \alpha \beta &  \beta ^2\\
\alpha \gamma & \alpha \delta + \beta \gamma & \beta \delta\\
\gamma^2    & 2 \gamma \delta  & \delta^2
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 &  -1\\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
-1    & 0  & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

It is not amazingly difficult to prove these are all. The first and third columns of the right hand matrix must be null vectors of $y^2 - z x,$ with coprime entries. It follows that the columns are some $(r^2,rs,s^2)$ and then some $\pm(u^2, uv,v^2).$ Then fiddle with the second column until it works.

This business is also discussed in Cassels, *Rational Quadratic Forms,* especially pages 301-303, chapter 13 section 5, "Isotropic Ternary Forms." 
He gives the observation of Fricke and Klein (1897), pages 507-508 as I recall, that any isotropic ternary integrally represents an integer multiple of $y^2 - zx.$ I first found that in a paper by Plesken. I wrote up a proof using no projective geometry methods, let me find that.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1972120/ternary-quadratic-forms/1976199#1976199

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!  One thing I'm a little puzzled over still.  Fixing some reasonably large value of the quadratic form, there are infinitely many integral points taking this value, but even just considering positive triples $(a,b,c)$ in my basis, there will be a large, but finite number of them having this fixed value.  So you're saying the symmetry group you propose is responsible for all of these integral points taking the same value?  It seems too small for that to me.

Comment: @StephenPietromonaco posted a separate answer. Suggest you do similar, solve $P^T H P = H$ with integral $P$ by computer, keep when either $P_{11} > 0$ or $P_{11} = 0$ and at least one of $P_{13}$ or $P_{31}$ is positive. For you, as you are skeptical, build in a command that checks each successful matrix for the format I indicate, which is formula (7) on page 14 of Fricke Klein (1897), or (3) on page 451. I understand the AMS is now publishing an English translation. OR, I can email you a huge output file.

Answer (score 1):

$P^T H P = H,$ where $H$ is the Hessian of $y^2 - zx,$ and $P$ has all integer entires

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./homothety_indef 0 1 0 0 -1 0   0 1 0 0 -1 0  15


Mon Dec 11 11:43:01 PST 2017

             P                                 P^T

      0      0      1 transposed        0      0      1
      0     -1      3 transposed        0     -1     -6
      1     -6      9 transposed        1      3      9

      0      0      1 transposed        0      0      1
      0     -1      2 transposed        0     -1     -4
      1     -4      4 transposed        1      2      4

      0      0      1 transposed        0      0      1
      0     -1      1 transposed        0     -1     -2
      1     -2      1 transposed        1      1      1

      0      0      1 transposed        0      0      1
      0     -1      0 transposed        0     -1      0
      1      0      0 transposed        1      0      0

      0      0      1 transposed        0      0      1
      0     -1     -1 transposed        0     -1      2
      1      2      1 transposed        1     -1      1

      0      0      1 transposed        0      0      1
      0     -1     -2 transposed        0     -1      4
      1      4      4 transposed        1     -2      4

      0      0      1 transposed        0      0      1
      0     -1     -3 transposed        0     -1      6
      1      6      9 transposed        1     -3      9

      0      0      1 transposed        0      0      1
      0      1     -3 transposed        0      1     -6
      1     -6      9 transposed        1     -3      9

      0      0      1 transposed        0      0      1
      0      1     -2 transposed        0      1     -4
      1     -4      4 transposed        1     -2      4

      0      0      1 transposed        0      0      1
      0      1     -1 transposed        0      1     -2
      1     -2      1 transposed        1     -1      1

      0      0      1 transposed        0      0      1
      0      1      0 transposed        0      1      0
      1      0      0 transposed        1      0      0

      0      0      1 transposed        0      0      1
      0      1      1 transposed        0      1      2
      1      2      1 transposed        1      1      1

      0      0      1 transposed        0      0      1
      0      1      2 transposed        0      1      4
      1      4      4 transposed        1      2      4

      0      0      1 transposed        0      0      1
      0      1      3 transposed        0      1      6
      1      6      9 transposed        1      3      9

      1     -2      1 transposed        1     -3      9
     -3      5     -2 transposed       -2      5    -12
      9    -12      4 transposed        1     -2      4

      1      0      0 transposed        1     -3      9
     -3     -1      0 transposed        0     -1      6
      9      6      1 transposed        0      0      1

      1      0      0 transposed        1     -3      9
     -3      1      0 transposed        0      1     -6
      9     -6      1 transposed        0      0      1

      1      2      1 transposed        1     -3      9
     -3     -5     -2 transposed        2     -5     12
      9     12      4 transposed        1     -2      4

      1     -4      4 transposed        1     -2      4
     -2      7     -6 transposed       -4      7    -12
      4    -12      9 transposed        4     -6      9

      1     -2      1 transposed        1     -2      4
     -2      3     -1 transposed       -2      3     -4
      4     -4      1 transposed        1     -1      1

      1     -2      1 transposed        1     -2      4
     -2      5     -3 transposed       -2      5    -12
      4    -12      9 transposed        1     -3      9

      1      0      0 transposed        1     -2      4
     -2     -1      0 transposed        0     -1      4
      4      4      1 transposed        0      0      1

      1      0      0 transposed        1     -2      4
     -2      1      0 transposed        0      1     -4
      4     -4      1 transposed        0      0      1

      1      2      1 transposed        1     -2      4
     -2     -5     -3 transposed        2     -5     12
      4     12      9 transposed        1     -3      9

      1      2      1 transposed        1     -2      4
     -2     -3     -1 transposed        2     -3      4
      4      4      1 transposed        1     -1      1

      1      4      4 transposed        1     -2      4
     -2     -7     -6 transposed        4     -7     12
      4     12      9 transposed        4     -6      9

      1     -6      9 transposed        1     -1      1
     -1      5     -6 transposed       -6      5     -4
      1     -4      4 transposed        9     -6      4

      1     -4      4 transposed        1     -1      1
     -1      3     -2 transposed       -4      3     -2
      1     -2      1 transposed        4     -2      1

      1     -4      4 transposed        1     -1      1
     -1      5     -6 transposed       -4      5     -6
      1     -6      9 transposed        4     -6      9

      1     -2      1 transposed        1     -1      1
     -1      1      0 transposed       -2      1      0
      1      0      0 transposed        1      0      0

      1     -2      1 transposed        1     -1      1
     -1      3     -2 transposed       -2      3     -4
      1     -4      4 transposed        1     -2      4

      1      0      0 transposed        1     -1      1
     -1     -1      0 transposed        0     -1      2
      1      2      1 transposed        0      0      1

      1      0      0 transposed        1     -1      1
     -1      1      0 transposed        0      1     -2
      1     -2      1 transposed        0      0      1

      1      2      1 transposed        1     -1      1
     -1     -3     -2 transposed        2     -3      4
      1      4      4 transposed        1     -2      4

      1      2      1 transposed        1     -1      1
     -1     -1      0 transposed        2     -1      0
      1      0      0 transposed        1      0      0

      1      4      4 transposed        1     -1      1
     -1     -5     -6 transposed        4     -5      6
      1      6      9 transposed        4     -6      9

      1      4      4 transposed        1     -1      1
     -1     -3     -2 transposed        4     -3      2
      1      2      1 transposed        4     -2      1

      1      6      9 transposed        1     -1      1
     -1     -5     -6 transposed        6     -5      4
      1      4      4 transposed        9     -6      4

      1     -6      9 transposed        1      0      0
      0     -1      3 transposed       -6     -1      0
      0      0      1 transposed        9      3      1

      1     -6      9 transposed        1      0      0
      0      1     -3 transposed       -6      1      0
      0      0      1 transposed        9     -3      1

      1     -4      4 transposed        1      0      0
      0     -1      2 transposed       -4     -1      0
      0      0      1 transposed        4      2      1

      1     -4      4 transposed        1      0      0
      0      1     -2 transposed       -4      1      0
      0      0      1 transposed        4     -2      1

      1     -2      1 transposed        1      0      0
      0     -1      1 transposed       -2     -1      0
      0      0      1 transposed        1      1      1

      1     -2      1 transposed        1      0      0
      0      1     -1 transposed       -2      1      0
      0      0      1 transposed        1     -1      1

      1      0      0 transposed        1      0      0
      0     -1      0 transposed        0     -1      0
      0      0      1 transposed        0      0      1

      1      0      0 transposed        1      0      0
      0      1      0 transposed        0      1      0
      0      0      1 transposed        0      0      1

      1      2      1 transposed        1      0      0
      0     -1     -1 transposed        2     -1      0
      0      0      1 transposed        1     -1      1

      1      2      1 transposed        1      0      0
      0      1      1 transposed        2      1      0
      0      0      1 transposed        1      1      1

      1      4      4 transposed        1      0      0
      0     -1     -2 transposed        4     -1      0
      0      0      1 transposed        4     -2      1

      1      4      4 transposed        1      0      0
      0      1      2 transposed        4      1      0
      0      0      1 transposed        4      2      1

      1      6      9 transposed        1      0      0
      0     -1     -3 transposed        6     -1      0
      0      0      1 transposed        9     -3      1

      1      6      9 transposed        1      0      0
      0      1      3 transposed        6      1      0
      0      0      1 transposed        9      3      1

      1     -6      9 transposed        1      1      1
      1     -5      6 transposed       -6     -5     -4
      1     -4      4 transposed        9      6      4

      1     -4      4 transposed        1      1      1
      1     -5      6 transposed       -4     -5     -6
      1     -6      9 transposed        4      6      9

      1     -4      4 transposed        1      1      1
      1     -3      2 transposed       -4     -3     -2
      1     -2      1 transposed        4      2      1

      1     -2      1 transposed        1      1      1
      1     -3      2 transposed       -2     -3     -4
      1     -4      4 transposed        1      2      4

      1     -2      1 transposed        1      1      1
      1     -1      0 transposed       -2     -1      0
      1      0      0 transposed        1      0      0

      1      0      0 transposed        1      1      1
      1     -1      0 transposed        0     -1     -2
      1     -2      1 transposed        0      0      1

      1      0      0 transposed        1      1      1
      1      1      0 transposed        0      1      2
      1      2      1 transposed        0      0      1

      1      2      1 transposed        1      1      1
      1      1      0 transposed        2      1      0
      1      0      0 transposed        1      0      0

      1      2      1 transposed        1      1      1
      1      3      2 transposed        2      3      4
      1      4      4 transposed        1      2      4

      1      4      4 transposed        1      1      1
      1      3      2 transposed        4      3      2
      1      2      1 transposed        4      2      1

      1      4      4 transposed        1      1      1
      1      5      6 transposed        4      5      6
      1      6      9 transposed        4      6      9

      1      6      9 transposed        1      1      1
      1      5      6 transposed        6      5      4
      1      4      4 transposed        9      6      4

      1     -4      4 transposed        1      2      4
      2     -7      6 transposed       -4     -7    -12
      4    -12      9 transposed        4      6      9

      1     -2      1 transposed        1      2      4
      2     -5      3 transposed       -2     -5    -12
      4    -12      9 transposed        1      3      9

      1     -2      1 transposed        1      2      4
      2     -3      1 transposed       -2     -3     -4
      4     -4      1 transposed        1      1      1

      1      0      0 transposed        1      2      4
      2     -1      0 transposed        0     -1     -4
      4     -4      1 transposed        0      0      1

      1      0      0 transposed        1      2      4
      2      1      0 transposed        0      1      4
      4      4      1 transposed        0      0      1

      1      2      1 transposed        1      2      4
      2      3      1 transposed        2      3      4
      4      4      1 transposed        1      1      1

      1      2      1 transposed        1      2      4
      2      5      3 transposed        2      5     12
      4     12      9 transposed        1      3      9

      1      4      4 transposed        1      2      4
      2      7      6 transposed        4      7     12
      4     12      9 transposed        4      6      9

      1     -2      1 transposed        1      3      9
      3     -5      2 transposed       -2     -5    -12
      9    -12      4 transposed        1      2      4

      1      0      0 transposed        1      3      9
      3     -1      0 transposed        0     -1     -6
      9     -6      1 transposed        0      0      1

      1      0      0 transposed        1      3      9
      3      1      0 transposed        0      1      6
      9      6      1 transposed        0      0      1

      1      2      1 transposed        1      3      9
      3      5      2 transposed        2      5     12
      9     12      4 transposed        1      2      4

      4     -4      1 transposed        4     -6      9
     -6      5     -1 transposed       -4      5     -6
      9     -6      1 transposed        1     -1      1

      4     -4      1 transposed        4     -6      9
     -6      7     -2 transposed       -4      7    -12
      9    -12      4 transposed        1     -2      4

      4      4      1 transposed        4     -6      9
     -6     -7     -2 transposed        4     -7     12
      9     12      4 transposed        1     -2      4

      4      4      1 transposed        4     -6      9
     -6     -5     -1 transposed        4     -5      6
      9      6      1 transposed        1     -1      1

      4    -12      9 transposed        4     -2      1
     -2      5     -3 transposed      -12      5     -2
      1     -2      1 transposed        9     -3      1

      4    -12      9 transposed        4     -2      1
     -2      7     -6 transposed      -12      7     -4
      1     -4      4 transposed        9     -6      4

      4     -4      1 transposed        4     -2      1
     -2      1      0 transposed       -4      1      0
      1      0      0 transposed        1      0      0

      4     -4      1 transposed        4     -2      1
     -2      3     -1 transposed       -4      3     -2
      1     -2      1 transposed        1     -1      1

      4      4      1 transposed        4     -2      1
     -2     -3     -1 transposed        4     -3      2
      1      2      1 transposed        1     -1      1

      4      4      1 transposed        4     -2      1
     -2     -1      0 transposed        4     -1      0
      1      0      0 transposed        1      0      0

      4     12      9 transposed        4     -2      1
     -2     -7     -6 transposed       12     -7      4
      1      4      4 transposed        9     -6      4

      4     12      9 transposed        4     -2      1
     -2     -5     -3 transposed       12     -5      2
      1      2      1 transposed        9     -3      1

      4    -12      9 transposed        4      2      1
      2     -7      6 transposed      -12     -7     -4
      1     -4      4 transposed        9      6      4

      4    -12      9 transposed        4      2      1
      2     -5      3 transposed      -12     -5     -2
      1     -2      1 transposed        9      3      1

      4     -4      1 transposed        4      2      1
      2     -3      1 transposed       -4     -3     -2
      1     -2      1 transposed        1      1      1

      4     -4      1 transposed        4      2      1
      2     -1      0 transposed       -4     -1      0
      1      0      0 transposed        1      0      0

      4      4      1 transposed        4      2      1
      2      1      0 transposed        4      1      0
      1      0      0 transposed        1      0      0

      4      4      1 transposed        4      2      1
      2      3      1 transposed        4      3      2
      1      2      1 transposed        1      1      1

      4     12      9 transposed        4      2      1
      2      5      3 transposed       12      5      2
      1      2      1 transposed        9      3      1

      4     12      9 transposed        4      2      1
      2      7      6 transposed       12      7      4
      1      4      4 transposed        9      6      4

      4     -4      1 transposed        4      6      9
      6     -7      2 transposed       -4     -7    -12
      9    -12      4 transposed        1      2      4

      4     -4      1 transposed        4      6      9
      6     -5      1 transposed       -4     -5     -6
      9     -6      1 transposed        1      1      1

      4      4      1 transposed        4      6      9
      6      5      1 transposed        4      5      6
      9      6      1 transposed        1      1      1

      4      4      1 transposed        4      6      9
      6      7      2 transposed        4      7     12
      9     12      4 transposed        1      2      4

      9    -12      4 transposed        9     -6      4
     -6      7     -2 transposed      -12      7     -4
      4     -4      1 transposed        4     -2      1

      9     -6      1 transposed        9     -6      4
     -6      5     -1 transposed       -6      5     -4
      4     -4      1 transposed        1     -1      1

      9      6      1 transposed        9     -6      4
     -6     -5     -1 transposed        6     -5      4
      4      4      1 transposed        1     -1      1

      9     12      4 transposed        9     -6      4
     -6     -7     -2 transposed       12     -7      4
      4      4      1 transposed        4     -2      1

      9    -12      4 transposed        9     -3      1
     -3      5     -2 transposed      -12      5     -2
      1     -2      1 transposed        4     -2      1

      9     -6      1 transposed        9     -3      1
     -3      1      0 transposed       -6      1      0
      1      0      0 transposed        1      0      0

      9      6      1 transposed        9     -3      1
     -3     -1      0 transposed        6     -1      0
      1      0      0 transposed        1      0      0

      9     12      4 transposed        9     -3      1
     -3     -5     -2 transposed       12     -5      2
      1      2      1 transposed        4     -2      1

      9    -12      4 transposed        9      3      1
      3     -5      2 transposed      -12     -5     -2
      1     -2      1 transposed        4      2      1

      9     -6      1 transposed        9      3      1
      3     -1      0 transposed       -6     -1      0
      1      0      0 transposed        1      0      0

      9      6      1 transposed        9      3      1
      3      1      0 transposed        6      1      0
      1      0      0 transposed        1      0      0

      9     12      4 transposed        9      3      1
      3      5      2 transposed       12      5      2
      1      2      1 transposed        4      2      1

      9    -12      4 transposed        9      6      4
      6     -7      2 transposed      -12     -7     -4
      4     -4      1 transposed        4      2      1

      9     -6      1 transposed        9      6      4
      6     -5      1 transposed       -6     -5     -4
      4     -4      1 transposed        1      1      1

      9      6      1 transposed        9      6      4
      6      5      1 transposed        6      5      4
      4      4      1 transposed        1      1      1

      9     12      4 transposed        9      6      4
      6      7      2 transposed       12      7      4
      4      4      1 transposed        4      2      1



             -1 :     0     1          0      0   -1    0
             -1 :     0     1          0      0   -1    0


-1 =  -1 *  1 
-1 =  -1 *  1 
Mon Dec 11 11:43:02 PST 2017
```