# Solutions to a quadratic diophantine equation $17x^2 + 29y^2 = 41z^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find all positive integer solutions to the equation $17x^2 + 29y^2 = 41z^2$

Although I have got a simple instance $(3,8,7)$, I still don't know the form of general solution.

Comment: You already found one, then it has infinitely many via intersecting lines with rational slopes.

Comment: Not forgetting that the technique in pisco's comment gives you all the solutions.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2773097/how-to-find-all-rational-solutions-of-x2-3y2-7/2788381#2788381

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I put all the integer solutions, four Pythagorean Triples type recipes. Because I Care.

Answer (score 3):

All (primitive) solutions can be found from four Pythagorean Triple type recipes, along with absolute value signs when needed.  Give me some time, I will also typeset the formulae.

Let's see. If you use coprime $(u,v)$ and get a triple from one of the recipes ABCD that is NOT primitive, just throw that one out. The, well, advantage of going into this much detail, compared with the general rational solution (of pisco and S. Dolan) is that we know the gcd of the resulting triple. To find all integral triples up to some bound, we just look at the (positive definite binary form) definitions of $z$ and deduce bounds from that.

A:

$$ x = 36  u^2 - 34  u  v - 25  v^2  $$
$$   y = 14  u^2 + 46  u  v - 12  v^2 $$
$$  z = 26  u^2 - 2  u  v +19  v^2 $$

B:

$$ x = 76  u^2 - 62  u  v - 3  v^2  $$
    $$   y = 66  u^2 + 26  u  v - 8  v^2 $$
      $$  z = 74  u^2 - 10  u  v +7  v^2 $$

C:

$$ x = 50  u^2 - 34  u  v - 18  v^2  $$
$$ y = 24  u^2 + 46  u  v - 7  v^2 $$
$$ z = 38  u^2 + 2  u  v +13  v^2 $$

D:
$$ x = 6  u^2 - 62  u  v - 38  v^2  $$
$$ y = 16  u^2 + 26  u  v - 33  v^2 $$
$$ z = 14  u^2 + 10  u  v + 37  v^2 $$

==========================================================================

```
Tue Oct 29 13:25:20 PDT 2019
         7  x,y,z             3         8         7 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
         7  x,y,z             3         8         7   u,v      0    1      B    
         7  x,y,z             3         8         7   u,v      0   -1      B    
        13  x,y,z            18         7        13 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
        13  x,y,z            18         7        13   u,v      0    1      C    
        13  x,y,z            18         7        13   u,v      0   -1      C    
        19  x,y,z            25        12        19 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
        19  x,y,z            25        12        19   u,v      0    1      A    
        19  x,y,z            25        12        19   u,v      0   -1      A    
        37  x,y,z            38        33        37 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
        37  x,y,z            38        33        37   u,v      0    1      D    
        37  x,y,z            38        33        37   u,v      0   -1      D    
        41  x,y,z            30        43        41 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
        41  x,y,z            30        43        41   u,v      1   -1      D    
        43  x,y,z            23        48        43 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
        43  x,y,z            23        48        43   u,v      1    1      A    
        47  x,y,z            45        44        47 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
        47  x,y,z            45        44        47   u,v      1   -1      A    
        49  x,y,z            66        29        49 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
        49  x,y,z            66        29        49   u,v      1   -1      C    
        53  x,y,z             2        63        53 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
        53  x,y,z             2        63        53   u,v      1    1      C    
        61  x,y,z            94         9        61 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
        61  x,y,z            94         9        61   u,v      1    1      D    
        71  x,y,z            11        84        71 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
        71  x,y,z            11        84        71   u,v      1    1      B    
        73  x,y,z           110        21        73 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
        73  x,y,z           110        21        73   u,v      2   -1      D    
        91  x,y,z           135        32        91 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
        91  x,y,z           135        32        91   u,v      1   -1      B    
       107  x,y,z           137        72       107 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       107  x,y,z           137        72       107   u,v      1    3      B    
       113  x,y,z           138        83       113 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       113  x,y,z           138        83       113   u,v      2    1      D    
       127  x,y,z           187        48       127 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       127  x,y,z           187        48       127   u,v      2   -1      A    
       133  x,y,z           202        33       133 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       133  x,y,z           202        33       133   u,v      3   -1      D    
       149  x,y,z            10       177       149 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       149  x,y,z            10       177       149   u,v      1   -3      C    
       161  x,y,z           214        99       161 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       161  x,y,z           214        99       161   u,v      1    3      C    
       161  x,y,z           250         3       161 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       161  x,y,z           250         3       161   u,v      2   -1      C    
       167  x,y,z           235        84       167 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       167  x,y,z           235        84       167   u,v      1   -3      B    
       169  x,y,z           114       181       169 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       169  x,y,z           114       181       169   u,v      2    1      C    
       191  x,y,z           291        44       191 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       191  x,y,z           291        44       191   u,v      1    3      A    
       193  x,y,z           170       189       193 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       193  x,y,z           170       189       193   u,v      3    1      D    
       199  x,y,z           309         4       199 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       199  x,y,z           309         4       199   u,v      1    5      B    
       247  x,y,z           197       252       247 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       247  x,y,z           197       252       247   u,v      3    1      A    
       257  x,y,z           242       243       257 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       257  x,y,z           242       243       257   u,v      2   -3      C    
       259  x,y,z           401        24       259 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       259  x,y,z           401        24       259   u,v      3   -1      A    
       263  x,y,z           285       224       263 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       263  x,y,z           285       224       263   u,v      2    3      A    
       281  x,y,z           166       309       281 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       281  x,y,z           166       309       281   u,v      2    3      C    
       283  x,y,z           177       308       283 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       283  x,y,z           177       308       283   u,v      2    1      B    
       299  x,y,z           311       264       299 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       299  x,y,z           311       264       299   u,v      1   -5      B    
       299  x,y,z            95       348       299 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       299  x,y,z            95       348       299   u,v      2    3      B    
       301  x,y,z           190       327       301 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       301  x,y,z           190       327       301   u,v      4    1      D    
       317  x,y,z           150       359       317 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       317  x,y,z           150       359       317   u,v      1   -3      D    
       329  x,y,z            54       389       329 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       329  x,y,z            54       389       329   u,v      2   -3      D    
       337  x,y,z           422       237       337 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       337  x,y,z           422       237       337   u,v      5   -1      D    
       347  x,y,z           505       144       347 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       347  x,y,z           505       144       347   u,v      1    7      B    
       349  x,y,z           534        71       349 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       349  x,y,z           534        71       349   u,v      3   -1      C    
       353  x,y,z           230       381       353 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       353  x,y,z           230       381       353   u,v      1   -5      C    
       361  x,y,z           330       347       361 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       361  x,y,z           330       347       361   u,v      3    1      C    
       371  x,y,z           391       324       371 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       371  x,y,z           391       324       371   u,v      2    5      B    
       373  x,y,z           570        79       373 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       373  x,y,z           570        79       373   u,v      1    5      C    
       419  x,y,z           649        36       419 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       419  x,y,z           649        36       419   u,v      2   -3      B    
       427  x,y,z           415       396       427 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       427  x,y,z           415       396       427   u,v      4    1      A    
       437  x,y,z           198       497       437 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       437  x,y,z           198       497       437   u,v      5    1      D    
       437  x,y,z           498       353       437 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       437  x,y,z           498       353       437   u,v      4   -3      D    
       443  x,y,z           687        28       443 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       443  x,y,z           687        28       443   u,v      4   -1      A    
       449  x,y,z           690        77       449 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       449  x,y,z           690        77       449   u,v      2    3      D    
       457  x,y,z            90       539       457 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       457  x,y,z            90       539       457   u,v      2   -5      C    
       481  x,y,z           550       387       481 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       481  x,y,z           550       387       481   u,v      6   -1      D    
       487  x,y,z           363       508       487 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       487  x,y,z           363       508       487   u,v      1   -7      B    
       491  x,y,z           759        56       491 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       491  x,y,z           759        56       491   u,v      1    5      A    
       497  x,y,z           590       381       497 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       497  x,y,z           590       381       497   u,v      2    5      C    
       499  x,y,z           711       236       499 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       499  x,y,z           711       236       499   u,v      2    7      B    
       511  x,y,z           419       516       511 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       511  x,y,z           419       516       511   u,v      1   -5      A    
       559  x,y,z           821       216       559 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       559  x,y,z           821       216       559   u,v      2    5      A    
       563  x,y,z            57       668       563 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       563  x,y,z            57       668       563   u,v      4    3      A    
       571  x,y,z           849       196       571 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       571  x,y,z           849       196       571   u,v      2   -5      B    
       599  x,y,z           141       704       599 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       599  x,y,z           141       704       599   u,v      2   -5      A    
       601  x,y,z           194       699       601 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       601  x,y,z           194       699       601   u,v      6    1      D    
       611  x,y,z           759       436       611 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       611  x,y,z           759       436       611   u,v      4   -3      A    
       613  x,y,z           918       193       613 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       613  x,y,z           918       193       613   u,v      4   -1      C    
       637  x,y,z           510       649       637 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       637  x,y,z           510       649       637   u,v      3   -5      C    
       643  x,y,z           495       664       643 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       643  x,y,z           495       664       643   u,v      3    1      B    
       653  x,y,z           690       569       653 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       653  x,y,z           690       569       653   u,v      7   -1      D    
       659  x,y,z           705       568       659 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       659  x,y,z           705       568       659   u,v      5    1      A    
       661  x,y,z           594       641       661 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       661  x,y,z           594       641       661   u,v      1   -7      C    
       677  x,y,z           990       271       677 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       677  x,y,z           990       271       677   u,v      4    3      D    
       679  x,y,z          1045       108       679 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       679  x,y,z          1045       108       679   u,v      5   -1      A    
       679  x,y,z           811       516       679 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       679  x,y,z           811       516       679   u,v      3    5      A    
       683  x,y,z          1055        84       683 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       683  x,y,z          1055        84       683   u,v      2    9      B    
       689  x,y,z          1070         3       689 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       689  x,y,z          1070         3       689   u,v      1    7      C    
       691  x,y,z           321       784       691 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       691  x,y,z           321       784       691   u,v      3    5      B    
       701  x,y,z          1046       231       701 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       701  x,y,z          1046       231       701   u,v      4   -3      C    
       703  x,y,z           867       508       703 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       703  x,y,z           867       508       703   u,v      3   -1      B    
       739  x,y,z           209       864       739 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       739  x,y,z           209       864       739   u,v      3   -5      A    
       749  x,y,z           230       873       749 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       749  x,y,z           230       873       749   u,v      4    3      C    
       761  x,y,z           206       891       761 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       761  x,y,z           206       891       761   u,v      2   -7      C    
       791  x,y,z           165       932       791 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       791  x,y,z           165       932       791   u,v      5    3      A    
       793  x,y,z           178       933       793 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       793  x,y,z           178       933       793   u,v      7    1      D    
       809  x,y,z          1254        59       809 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       809  x,y,z          1254        59       809   u,v      7   -3      D    
       811  x,y,z           969       616       811 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       811  x,y,z           969       616       811   u,v      1   11      B    
       817  x,y,z          1158       397       817 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       817  x,y,z          1158       397       817   u,v      2    7      C    
       851  x,y,z          1185       448       851 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       851  x,y,z          1185       448       851   u,v      5   -3      A    
       851  x,y,z           729       844       851 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       851  x,y,z           729       844       851   u,v      4    5      A    
       853  x,y,z           842       783       853 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       853  x,y,z           842       783       853   u,v      8   -1      D    
       881  x,y,z           306      1021       881 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       881  x,y,z           306      1021       881   u,v      2   -5      D    
       889  x,y,z           634       939       889 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       889  x,y,z           634       939       889   u,v      1   -5      D    
       893  x,y,z          1030       711       893 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       893  x,y,z          1030       711       893   u,v      4   -5      C    
       923  x,y,z          1423       132       923 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       923  x,y,z          1423       132       923   u,v      2   11      B    
       931  x,y,z           631       996       931 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       931  x,y,z           631       996       931   u,v      4   -5      A    
       937  x,y,z           282      1093       937 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       937  x,y,z           282      1093       937   u,v      3   -7      C    
       943  x,y,z          1067       768       943 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       943  x,y,z          1067       768       943   u,v      6    1      A    
       943  x,y,z          1427       252       943 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       943  x,y,z          1427       252       943   u,v      1    7      A    
       949  x,y,z           386      1089       949 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       949  x,y,z           386      1089       949   u,v      4   -5      D    
       953  x,y,z          1402       363       953 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       953  x,y,z          1402       363       953   u,v      5   -1      C    
       967  x,y,z          1475       216       967 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       967  x,y,z          1475       216       967   u,v      6   -1      A    
       971  x,y,z           951       896       971 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       971  x,y,z           951       896       971   u,v      1   -7      A    
       973  x,y,z          1062       823       973 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       973  x,y,z          1062       823       973   u,v      5    1      C    
       973  x,y,z           330      1129       973 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       973  x,y,z           330      1129       973   u,v      4    5      C    
       989  x,y,z          1254       679       989 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       989  x,y,z          1254       679       989   u,v      1    5      D    
       989  x,y,z          1530       103       989 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       989  x,y,z          1530       103       989   u,v      8   -3      D    
       991  x,y,z          1539         4       991 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
       991  x,y,z          1539         4       991   u,v      3   -5      B    
      1007  x,y,z          1557       112      1007 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1007  x,y,z          1557       112      1007   u,v      2    7      A    
      1013  x,y,z           150      1199      1013 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1013  x,y,z           150      1199      1013   u,v      8    1      D    
      1021  x,y,z          1146       839      1021 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1021  x,y,z          1146       839      1021   u,v      3    7      C    
      1031  x,y,z           395      1188      1031 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1031  x,y,z           395      1188      1031   u,v      1  -11      B    
      1043  x,y,z          1177       852      1043 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1043  x,y,z          1177       852      1043   u,v      2   -9      B    
      1063  x,y,z           605      1176      1063 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1063  x,y,z           605      1176      1063   u,v      2   -7      A    
      1081  x,y,z          1006      1029      1081 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1081  x,y,z          1006      1029      1081   u,v      9   -1      D    
      1081  x,y,z          1546       501      1081 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1081  x,y,z          1546       501      1081   u,v      2    5      D    
      1097  x,y,z           578      1227      1097 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1097  x,y,z           578      1227      1097   u,v      5    3      C    
      1109  x,y,z          1714       129      1109 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1109  x,y,z          1714       129      1109   u,v      1    9      C    
      1123  x,y,z          1615       504      1123 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1123  x,y,z          1615       504      1123   u,v      3    7      A    
      1127  x,y,z          1237       948      1127 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1127  x,y,z          1237       948      1127   u,v      1   13      B    
      1127  x,y,z           445      1296      1127 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1127  x,y,z           445      1296      1127   u,v      4    3      B    
      1129  x,y,z          1126      1029      1129 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1129  x,y,z          1126      1029      1129   u,v      6   -5      D    
      1151  x,y,z           965      1152      1151 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1151  x,y,z           965      1152      1151   u,v      4    1      B    
      1159  x,y,z            99      1376      1159 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1159  x,y,z            99      1376      1159   u,v      4    5      B    
      1169  x,y,z           646      1299      1169 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1169  x,y,z           646      1299      1169   u,v      2   -9      C    
      1183  x,y,z          1725       484      1183 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1183  x,y,z          1725       484      1183   u,v      3   11      B    
      1201  x,y,z          1826       291      1201 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1201  x,y,z          1826       291      1201   u,v      3    5      D    
      1219  x,y,z          1815       412      1219 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1219  x,y,z          1815       412      1219   u,v      2   13      B    
      1219  x,y,z          1839       344      1219 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1219  x,y,z          1839       344      1219   u,v      3   -7      B    
      1229  x,y,z          1350      1033      1229 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1229  x,y,z          1350      1033      1229   u,v      7    3      D    
      1231  x,y,z          1461       944      1231 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1231  x,y,z          1461       944      1231   u,v      4   -1      B    
      1261  x,y,z           110      1497      1261 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1261  x,y,z           110      1497      1261   u,v      9    1      D    
      1261  x,y,z          1514       951      1261 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1261  x,y,z          1514       951      1261   u,v      7   -5      D    
      1279  x,y,z          1501       996      1279 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1279  x,y,z          1501       996      1279   u,v      7    1      A    
      1291  x,y,z          1601       924      1291 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1291  x,y,z          1601       924      1291   u,v      4    7      A    
      1301  x,y,z          1034      1329      1301 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1301  x,y,z          1034      1329      1301   u,v      4    7      C    
      1307  x,y,z          1977       352      1307 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1307  x,y,z          1977       352      1307   u,v      7   -1      A    
      1337  x,y,z          1182      1307      1337 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1337  x,y,z          1182      1307      1337   u,v     10   -1      D    
      1349  x,y,z          2094        49      1349 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1349  x,y,z          2094        49      1349   u,v      4    5      D    
      1351  x,y,z           349      1584      1351 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1351  x,y,z           349      1584      1351   u,v      6    5      A    
      1367  x,y,z          1933       672      1367 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1367  x,y,z          1933       672      1367   u,v      4   -3      B    
      1369  x,y,z          1986       581      1369 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1369  x,y,z          1986       581      1369   u,v      6   -1      C    
      1387  x,y,z           375      1624      1387 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1387  x,y,z           375      1624      1387   u,v      1  -13      B    
      1391  x,y,z          1259      1344      1391 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1391  x,y,z          1259      1344      1391   u,v      4    9      B    
      1393  x,y,z          1578      1133      1393 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1393  x,y,z          1578      1133      1393   u,v      6    1      C    
      1403  x,y,z           303      1652      1403 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1403  x,y,z           303      1652      1403   u,v      4   -7      A    
      1403  x,y,z           825      1544      1403 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1403  x,y,z           825      1544      1403   u,v      7    3      A    
      1433  x,y,z          2118       523      1433 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1433  x,y,z          2118       523      1433   u,v     10   -3      D    
      1459  x,y,z          2241       256      1459 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1459  x,y,z          2241       256      1459   u,v      3   13      B    
      1469  x,y,z          1446      1351      1469 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1469  x,y,z          1446      1351      1469   u,v      8    3      D    
      1471  x,y,z          1691      1176      1471 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1471  x,y,z          1691      1176      1471   u,v      6   -5      A    
      1487  x,y,z          2253       388      1487 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1487  x,y,z          2253       388      1487   u,v      7   -3      A    
      1499  x,y,z          1529      1344      1499 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1499  x,y,z          1529      1344      1499   u,v      1   15      B    
      1511  x,y,z          1515      1372      1511 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1511  x,y,z          1515      1372      1511   u,v      5    7      A    
      1559  x,y,z          2381       336      1559 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1559  x,y,z          2381       336      1559   u,v      4   -5      B    
      1571  x,y,z          2231       756      1571 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1571  x,y,z          2231       756      1571   u,v      2   15      B    
      1583  x,y,z          1683      1372      1583 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1583  x,y,z          1683      1372      1583   u,v      1   -9      A    
      1589  x,y,z          1754      1329      1589 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1589  x,y,z          1754      1329      1589   u,v      1  -11      C    
      1589  x,y,z           566      1839      1589 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1589  x,y,z           566      1839      1589   u,v      4   -9      C    
      1591  x,y,z          1875      1232      1591 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1591  x,y,z          1875      1232      1591   u,v      4   11      B    
      1607  x,y,z          2493        88      1607 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1607  x,y,z          2493        88      1607   u,v      2    9      A    
      1609  x,y,z          2326       699      1609 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1609  x,y,z          2326       699      1609   u,v      9   -5      D    
      1621  x,y,z          1370      1617      1621 BRUTE FORCE SEARCH  
      1621  x,y,z          1370      1617      1621   u,v     11   -1      D
```

===========================================================

Comment: Your answer is quite good, but I have another question. Why four familys of solutions, not more or less? Is there any basis for this? Thanks!

Comment: @Eufisky  it varies a good deal. It rises up a bit for each prime factor of the discriminant; any one of the recipes gives a multiple of every integer solution, then that common factor leads to another such recipe. Still not the whole story, but see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1972120/ternary-quadratic-forms/1976199#1976199

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the above comments:-

You can use your answer to find all other solutions as follows.

Let $X=\frac{x}{z},Y=\frac{y}{z}$ then $17X^2 + 29Y^2 = 41$.

Define rationals $U$ and $T$ by $U=X-\frac{3}{7},UT=\frac{8}{7}-Y$ then $$17(U^2 + \frac{6}{7}U)+29(U^2T^2-\frac{16}{7}UT)=0$$
$U=0$ gives the initial solution and so
$$17(U + \frac{6}{7})+29(UT^2-\frac{16}{7}T)=0$$
$$U=\frac{464T-102}{203T^2+119}$$

We can now express $X$ and $Y$ in terms of the rational parameter $T$. For any given $T$ you can just let $z$ be the l.c.m. of the denominators of $X$ and $Y$ and then $x,y,z$ will be an integer solution.

Answer (score 1):

Above equation shown below:

$17x^2 + 29y^2 = 41z^2$   ----$(1)$

Equation $(1)$ has parametric solution & is shown below:

$x=(123k^2-574k+428)$

$y=2(164k^2-287k+99)$

$z=(287k^2-566k+322)$

For, $k=1$ we get:

$(x,y,z)=(23,48,43)$

Comment: Care to explain how you got this?

Answer (score 0):

Above equation shown below:

$$17x^2 + 29y^2 = 41z^2 \;\;\;\;(1)$$

"OP" commented on a general form of equation, $(1)$

So equation $(1)$ can be written as:

$$ax^2 + by^2 = cz^2\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(2)$$

Equation $(2)$ has parametric solution:

$$(x,y,z)=[(2)(p-2),(p+1),(3)(p-1)],$$

$$(a,b,c))=[(2p^2-2p+2),((p^2+2p-5),(p^2-2p+3)].$$

For, $p=4$, we get after removing common factors:

$$(x,y,z)=(4,5,9),$$

$$(a,b,c)=(26,19,11).$$