# Find the general solutions of $x^2+qy^2-z^2=4n$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, integers, diophantine-approximation

I have this diophantine equation and i need the general solution form for it

the equation

$$x^2+qy^2-z^2=4n$$

some conditions
$y\le 0,x\ge 0,z\ge 0$ x,z are even or odd together

$n=5y+x-3xy$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74931/integral-solutions-of-x2y21-z2/789929#789929

Comment: $$z^2-x^2=(z-x)(z+x)=y^2-4n$$  There is always a solution for any numbers  $y,n$  .  It is only necessary to decompose the difference in the multipliers.

Comment: I don't think you need infinite descent; the given equation is equivalent to $x^2+y^2\equiv z^2\pmod{4}$, so it is enough to just check all possible values of x, y, and z mod 4 (of course, it is even faster if you only check the values of $x^2$, $y^2$, and $z^2$ mod 4)

Comment: 1- if i said that there is only one solution for this case while i know that if x is even then z is even too and odd if odd ,in addition to there is a relation between x,y and n where n= 5y+x-3xy .

Comment: 2- #individ can you explain the solution $qX^2+Y^2-Z^2=a$ it is too hard to solve with this method in your link it have many variables

Comment: I don't understand what You need decision? Suggested a few options - not satisfied. So what need???

Comment: #individ  calm down ! -in my research i have a problem of this diophantine equation $n^2+4r^2-s^2=(4/3)(5-(3n-5)(r-1))$  the only value i have is n but i know some properties about r  and s that's all and i knew that there is only one solution where n,s positive integers and r is negative integer