# Smallest possible value for x + y + z?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $x, y, z$ be integers with $2 < x < y < z$, and let $z$ be even.

> If $x^2 + y^2 = z^2 + 4$, what is the least possible value for $x+y+z$ ?

So far, I've realized that $z^2 + 4$ must be even, which means that $x^2 + y^2$ must be even, which means that $x$ and $y$ can either both be even or both be odd.

I'm pretty much stuck at this point. How could you solve this question without resorting to using programming?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read about Lagrangians and contrained optimisation?

Comment: Programming is the natural approach for this problem. It quickly finds the solution $$(x,y,z)=(8, 14, 16)$$
 and  there are only $5$ other solutions with $z < 40$, all of which have larger sums.

Comment: @anderstood: I could be mistaken, but I don't see how constrained optimization helps here, since the solutions must be integers. One dumb observation is that we must have $(y-2)(y+2) = (z-x)(z+x)$, so you can enumerate a list of squares minus $4$ and see which of these can be described as a difference of squares. Another small optimization is that $x$ and $y$ must in fact be even, since taking both sides mod $4$ gives $0$ on the RHS, as $z$ is even.

Comment: @AlexWertheim My bad I had missed the integer part, sorry.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74931/integral-solutions-of-x2y21-z2/789972#789972